# How do I toggle Android settings with a keyboard?

Tags: android

I'm trying to flip a toggle switch in the Android settings on my Dell Wyse Cloud Connect using my Bluetooth keyboard. Specifically I'm trying to turn the WiFi from "Off" to "On".

I can navigate the other settings without toggles just fine using arrow keys and enter but I can't seem to figure out how to flip the toggle.

Edit: I've tried pressing every key on the keyboard individually with the setting highlighted. Perhaps a key combination is required?

Comment: What keystrokes have you tried so far?

Comment: Edited to add attempted keystrokes.

Comment: Are you able to highlight the switch itself? As in, with WiFi selected, pressing right to move the selection from the WiFi entry to the toggle switch?

Comment: Good question. I don't think so. The entire setting gets highlighted and pressing left or right moves immediately to another menu at the top of the screen. (up/down/tab moves to next setting)

Comment: Could you tell us what keyboard you're using?

Comment: I'm using the [Logitech K810 Bluetooth Keyboard](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/bluetooth-illuminated-keyboard-k810). Actually was recommended by Dell to use with Cloud Connect.

Comment: Alright. What does enter, minus (-), and plus (+) do to the setting?

Comment: Sidenote: do you have a bluetooth mouse on hand?

Comment: I have an Apple Magic Mouse that I managed to connect, but I don't seem to have a cursor inside Android like on my Nvidia Shield. I also don't have touch capability on the monitor.

Comment: Quite the predicament. The device should have come with a Micro USB to USB cable. Do you have that on hand? Is there a USB mouse you can connect?